# Monitor MKMapView redraw events

Tags: ios, uiview, mapkit

I have some UI that I need to redraw based on changes to an MKMapView when the user pans or zooms the map.

Currently I am using a move event gesture recogniser and MKMapViewDelegate regionDidChangeAnimated messages to redraw my dependant UI. This is 90% of what I need.

The events I am missing are from the point the user lifts their finger (no more move events) to when the MKMapViewDelegate regionDidChangeAnimated message is fired. During that period the map slowly pans to a halt and my dependant UI is stuck with map tile content that is out of synch.

Is there a lower level API that will notify me when UIView (in this case MKMapView) content is redrawn?

**Update**

I tried creating a proxy MKMapView subclass that forwarded drawRect calls onto my supplied delegate. I get the first draw event but none of the subsequent ones, so this doesn't help with my predicament.

Comment: I have filed Apple Bug #13774496 related to this (not knowing when the map is finished drawing) and created an example app to show the issue still exists on iOS6: https://github.com/iwasrobbed/MapKitDelegateBug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, MKMapView is unfortunately [not KVO-compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370339/observing-the-region-of-mkmapview-via-kvo) for `@"region"`.

You might hack you way setting up an `NSTimer` in `regionWillChangeAnimated`, using it to refresh you UI during the scroll/pan/etc, and discarding it in `regionDidChangeAnimated`. Not quite elegant though, and it may not suit your needs if you need to be really fast.

Alternatively, you may look for the `UIScrollView` in MKMapView's subviews, and observe its `transform`.

(I haven't tested any of these.)

In any case, I doubt that monitoring redraw events on a `MKMapView` will be of any use : `MKMapView` uses `CATiledLayer` to perform its drawing asynchronously, so you can't even be sure *when* it's done.

---

Edit : This apparently does not work with iOS 6. Of course, this should not really come as a surprise. However, as far as I know, the delegate methods behave the same, so the OP's problem is still real. I haven't looked for an updated solution.

Comment: Thanks man. Your point about MKMapView not being KVO compliant saved me some time. I had already tried the timer option before posting and, as you suspected, it wasn't up to scratch. You get the tick because the solution involved digging through the view heirachy for the UIScrollView and using KVO on the contentOffset property. Do you mind if I edit your answer with the working code?

Comment: mkmapview doesn't seem to have a uiscrollview subview in ios6 :(

Comment: OP or @n-b, would you mind posting the code that worked for you? It would be useful to know what properties you were observing and see if how this works with newer versions of MapKit.

Answer (score 1):

Hate to post THESE kind of solutions, but.
MKMapView has many subview in itself.
In it's subviews hierarchy there's an view with class MKTiledView, which have TiledLayer as layer.

So, actually, you can't resolve notifications of rendering in "normal" way.

Tiled layer renders it's contents by constantly calling -drawLayer:inContext: method of it's delegate, which MKTiledView is. Those calls can be performed simultaneosly in different threads.

You're not receiving norifications(updates) from MKMapView because it isn't updating itself. Only underlying contents of it are updating.

So. There's always better solution exists.
My solution depends on view hierarchy and method's swizzling.
It's up to you, to use it or not.

Creating category-method in which we will post "update notifications" to custom view that need to be updated

```
@implementation UIView (Custom)

- (void)drawCustomLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
   NSLog(@"Need to draw custom layer :%@ in context %@, Thread: %@", layer, ctx, [NSThread currentThread]);

   // Calling old method
   [self drawCustomLayer:layer inContext:ctx];
}

@end
```

// Exchanging method implementation of MKTiledView to our custom implementation

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

Class tileViewclass = NSClassFromString(@"MKMapTileView");
Class viewClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIView");
SEL originalSelector = @selector(drawLayer:inContext:);
SEL newSelector = @selector(drawCustomLayer:inContext:);
Method origMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(tileViewclass, originalSelector);
Method newMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(viewClass, newSelector);
method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, newMethod);
```

Still looking for better solution.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the suggested solution. In the end it came a little late as I had just tried @nico_nico's UIScrollView suggestion and it works admirably.

Answer (score -1):

MKMapView has many subviews that redraws. It is very hard to find which view or layer drawed...

Alternatively you could try to find some of MKMapView properties are changed. You can do this with Key Value Observing (KVO) mechanics. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

Eg. (properties can be changed to whatever you need)

```
  [myMapView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"region" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
  [myMapView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"centerCoordinate" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

And you should implement `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    // Do something that you want with keyPath;
}
```

Whenever your mapView has new values for each property you defined, this method will be fired.

Comment: +1 Yours was a step in the right direction, so thanks :) As @nico_nico points out, the MKMapView wasn't KVO compliant for those properties. Also I noticed that your params from the addObserver call aren't quite right (mYMapView and self should be swapped). Thanks again.

Comment: :) thanks for your reply. @nico_nico is right. i havent noticed KVO compliation of MKMapView.